# SP2013 Search - Explanation of KnownTableTypes

Tags: 2013, search

Does anyone have a detailed description/documentation on **Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query.KnownTableTypes**?

I'm wondering why every "How to use a KeywordQuery in code"-article on the web just uses "KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults" and what the differences to the other TableTypes are:

```
ResultTableCollection rtc = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
var tables = rtc.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
var result = tables.FirstOrDefault();
```

The coresponding [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.sharepoint.search.query.knowntabletypes_members.aspx) is pretty featureless ... at least for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at page 91 of the MS-Search pdf protocol spec for KeywordQuery. This lists some of but not all the known table types for SP2013. Apparently, there is not an updated version of this document for SP2013 yet.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313119(v=office.12).aspx